# cmake error: no such file?

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, linker-errors

first of all i'm using clion and built-in cmake on ubuntu 17

**build massage log:**

```
[ 20%] Linking C executable pacman
cc: error: SDL2_image: No such file or directory
CMakeFiles/pacman.dir/build.make:172: recipe for target 'pacman' failed
make[3]: *** [pacman] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pacman.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pacman.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pacman.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pacman.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'pacman' failed
make: *** [pacman] Error 2
```

**cmakeList.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(pacman C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(SOURCE src/main.c src/input.c src/input.h src/view.c src/view.h src/models.h src/models.c)
add_executable(pacman "${SOURCE}")
include_directories(src)
include_directories(src/SDL2-2.0.7/include)
INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2IMAGE REQUIRED)
set(SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR "src/SDL2_image-2.0.2")
include_directories("${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(pacman "${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2IMAGE_LIBRARIES}")
```

**and a file named Makefile: (I don't know much about it! and the error finally rises from here, unfortunately)**

```
# Makefile for showimage

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = $(shell sdl2-config --cflags) -Wall -O
LIBS = $(shell sdl2-config --libs) -lSDL2_image
EXE = showimage

all: $(EXE)

showimage: showimage.c Makefile
    $(CC) -o $@ $@.c $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

clean:
    -rm *.o $(EXE)
```

note that i'm 100% sure i've installed all sdl2 libraries using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2*
```

and it worked right and everything finished without any errors output this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-mixer-dev' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-image-dev' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-gfx-dev' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-gfx-doc' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-dev' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-doc' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-ttf-dev' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-net-2.0-0' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-net-dev' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-image-2.0-0' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-2.0-0' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0' for glob 'libsdl2*'
Note, selecting 'libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0' for glob 'libsdl2*'
libsdl2-2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.0.6+dfsg1-3ubuntu1).
libsdl2-dev is already the newest version (2.0.6+dfsg1-3ubuntu1).
libsdl2-doc is already the newest version (2.0.6+dfsg1-3ubuntu1).
libsdl2-gfx-1.0-0 is already the newest version (1.0.1+dfsg-5).
libsdl2-gfx-dev is already the newest version (1.0.1+dfsg-5).
libsdl2-gfx-doc is already the newest version (1.0.1+dfsg-5).
libsdl2-image-2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.0.1+dfsg-3).
libsdl2-image-dev is already the newest version (2.0.1+dfsg-3).
libsdl2-mixer-2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.0.1+dfsg1-3).
libsdl2-mixer-dev is already the newest version (2.0.1+dfsg1-3).
libsdl2-net-2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.0.1+dfsg1-3).
libsdl2-net-dev is already the newest version (2.0.1+dfsg1-3).
libsdl2-ttf-2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.0.14+dfsg1-2).
libsdl2-ttf-dev is already the newest version (2.0.14+dfsg1-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

thanks for help beforehands:)))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it all by changing the cmake code this way:
simply giving the sdl directory paths manually!

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(pacman C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(SOURCE src/main.c src/input.c src/input.h src/view.c src/view.h src/models.h src/models.c src/controler.c src/controler.h)
add_executable(pacman "${SOURCE}")
include_directories(src)

include_directories("/usr/include/SDL2")
target_link_libraries(pacman m SDL2 SDL2_gfx SDL2_image)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_REENTRANT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find_library instead of PKG_SEARCH_MODULE

```
find_library(SDL2_LIBRARY NAME SDL2)
target_include_directories(pacman ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(pacman ${SDL2_LIBRARY})
```

If SDL2 is not found, you have to add the path to SDL2 to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, that's the place where CMake looks for installed software.

Comment: I left the rest of file unchanged but changed the PKG_SEARCH_MODULE to find_library just copying your code but this error rises {Make Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (target_include_directories):
  target_include_directories called with invalid arguments


CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
SDL2_LIBRARY
    linked by target "pacman" in directory /home/mrtalebi/Projects/CLionProjects/pacman}

Comment: I found the error rising from compiler linker command: like this and it rises that error:                                                                                                                              -o pacman -lSDL2 SDL2_image -lSDL2

Comment: You need to even add target_include_directories and target_link_directories just like the way I specified. do that and post here what happens

Comment: thank you for your help! cmake is much more hard coded than i expected!

Comment: No, actually cmake makes it easier for us..From your below reply I understand that u can check for package this way
find_package(SDL2 components gfx image)...anyways you figured it out.well and good !